# Formatting appended text using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

HTML code

```
<button id="btn1">show item no. 1</button>
<button id="btn2">show item no.2</button>
<div id="resulttext"></div>
```

JavaScript code

```
price1=20;
price2=50;
qty1=0;
qty2=0;
amount=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function(){
        qty1=qty1 + 1;
        amount=price1*qty1;
        $("resultqty").change(qty1);
        $("resultprice").change(amount);
        $("#resulttext").append("<div><button type='button' id='remove1' class='close pull-right' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>REGULAR BURGER" + "<p> Quantity:"+qty1+"</p><p> Unit Total:"+amount+"</div>");
    })
})
$(document).on('click', 'button#remove1', function(){        
     $(this).parent().remove();
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        qty2=qty2 + 1;
        amount=price2*qty2;
        $("resultqty").change(qty2);
        $("resultprice").change(amount);
        $("#resulttext").append("<div><button type='button' id='remove2' class='close pull-right' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>SPECIAL BURGER"+ "<p> Quantity:"+qty2+"</p><p> Unit Total:"+amount+"</div>");
    })
})
$(document).on('click', 'button#remove2', function(){        
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

The code above is actually working, but my main problem is that when I click a specific button, the text that must be appended should only appear once but the quantity and amount should still change, real-time, as you continuously click the same button.

And another thing is, I want to get the sum of the amount of both buttons and display it on the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:**

Here the HTML:

```
<button id="btn1">show item no. 1</button>
<button id="btn2">show item no.2</button>
<div id="resulttext"></div>
```

And here the js:

```
price1=20;
price2=50;
qty1=0;
qty2=0;
amount=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn1').click(function(){

        qty1=qty1 + 1;
        amount=price1*qty1;
        $("resultqty").change(qty1);
        $("resultprice").change(amount);
        if($("#part1").length>0){
            $("#part1").html("<div><button type='button' id='remove1' class='close pull-right' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>REGULAR BURGER" + "<p> Quantity:"+qty1+"</p><p> Unit Total:"+amount+"</div>");
        }else{
            $("#resulttext").append("<div id='part1'><div><button type='button' id='remove1' class='close pull-right' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>REGULAR BURGER" + "<p> Quantity:"+qty1+"</p><p> Unit Total:"+amount+"</div></div>");
        }
    })
})
$(document).on('click', 'button#remove1', function(){        
    $("#part1").html("");
});


$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn2').click(function(){
        qty2=qty2 + 1;
        amount=price2*qty2;
        $("resultqty").change(qty2);
        $("resultprice").change(amount);
        if($("#part2").length>0){
            $("#part2").html("<div><button type='button' id='remove2' class='close pull-right' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>SPECIAL BURGER"+ "<p> Quantity:"+qty2+"</p><p> Unit Total:"+amount+"</div>");
        }else{
            $("#resulttext").append("<div id='part2'><div><button type='button' id='remove2' class='close pull-right' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>SPECIAL BURGER"+ "<p> Quantity:"+qty2+"</p><p> Unit Total:"+amount+"</div></div>");
        }
    })
});
$(document).on('click', 'button#remove2', function(){        
    $("#part2").html("");
});
```

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/YLEXU/3/

Comment: it works almost on what I'm looking for but, I need to display both items and an x button will be the one to remove it, one at a time. @Jonathan

Comment: @Ritz de Guzman I edited the fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/YLEXU/2/](http://jsfiddle.net/YLEXU/2/). You need to create a wrapper for the descriptions and update only its content. I update the Answer too with complete example.

Answer (score 0):

change .append() to .html() and create new div with another ID.

```
jsfiddle.net/wjkH4/
```

Comment: it works almost on what I'm looking for but, I need to display both items and an x button will be the one to remove it, one at a time. I think I can't create another div for that because, id="resulttext" is the only id that should fetch all the data.